# Keras: Pixelwise class imbalance in binary image segmentation

Tags: keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I have a task in which I input a `500x500x1` image and get out a `500x500x1` binary segmentation. When working, only a small fraction of the `500x500` should be triggered (small "targets").  I'm using a sigmoid activation at the output.  Since such a small fraction is desired to be positive, the training tends to stall with all outputs at zero, or very close. I've written my own loss function that partially deals with it, but I'd like to use binary cross entropy with a class weighting if possible.

My question is in two parts:

1. If I naively apply `binary_crossentropy` as the loss to my `500x500x1` output, will it apply on a per pixel basis as desired?
2. Is there a way for keras to apply class weighting with the single sigmoid output per pixel?

Answer (score 6):

To answer your questions.

1. Yes, `binary_cross_entropy` will work per-pixel based, provided you feed to your image segmentation neural network pairs of the form (500x500x1 image(grayscale image) + `500x500x1` (corresponding mask to your image).
2. By feeding the parameter '`class_weight`' parameter in `model.fit()`

   Suppose you have 2 classes with 90%-10% distribution. Then you may want to penalise your algorithm 9 times more when it makes a mistake for the less well represented class(the class with 10% in this case). Suppose you have 900 examples of class 1 and 100 examples of class 2.

Then your class weights dictionary(there are multiple ways to compute it, what is important is to assign a greater weight to the less well represented class),

```
  class_weights = {0:1000/900,1:1000/100}
```

Example : `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 30, batch_size=32, class_weight=class_weight)`

**NOTE: This is available only on 2d cases(class_weight). For 3D or higher dimensional spaces, one should use 'sample_weights'. For segmentation purposes, you would rather use `sample_weights` parameter**.

3. The biggest gain you will have is by means of other loss functions. Other losses, apart from `binary_crossentropy` and `categorical_crossentropy`, inherently perform better on unbalanced datasets. `Dice Loss` is such a loss function.

Keras implementation:

```
    smooth = 1.

    def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
        y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
        intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
        return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    
    
    def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

4. You can also use as a loss function the sum of `binary_crossentropy`
   and other losses if it suits you : i.e. `loss = dice_loss + bce`

Comment: Thanks.  So even though the output only has a single valued output class from the sigmoid (vs two outputs, softmax style), keras is smart enough to understand what is meant by the two classes?  At present, I get a keyword error of some kind when I try to use class_weights with fit (just as you show syntax-wise) - I'm away from my office for a few days, so can't provide the exact error message at the moment.

Comment: The error I get is "'class_eight' not supported for 3+ dimensional targets".  Do I need to collapse my 500x500x1 down to a vector?

Comment: This thread has people wrestling with the same issue, and it looks like they vectorized and used sample_weights instead:  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653

Comment: Wow, good to know, honestly I did not know that. Then sample weights is the way to go, I will also modify my answer :D

Comment: I just love StackOverflow. You try to help some people with your ideas, and then someone else tells you a better/the true solution to the problem. Sharing is caring :D